# Is there a way to save and retrieve text from contenteditable data box in a specific file ? (All client side)

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm making statistical reports for customers and I chose HTML solution as report template.

I have this issue where I want a user to be able to **edit** a text box of a html document and **save** it (as soon as he leave the area or when clicking save button) to annotate things like graphics for instance.

The content should be printed **each time** he opens back the .html file. Also, there are potentially multiple html pages inside the report (one editable box per sub **html** pages is enough)

Moreover, a big **constraint** here is that this **html** file is **open locally** and should be **shared across users** (I have to stick with this all-client side solution for now but I'm planning on doing it server side).

As you may have understood already I can't use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) solution as it is system/user dependant and data won't stick if people are sharing the report.

I'd rather go with a solution where it is possible to save it in a **$UID**.txt file for instance (one **$UID** for each sub pages people wants to annotate) and retrieve it so as long as the state of the editable content is saved at the same place in the report folder architecture, it will be opened as is by every other people when they get this edited report.

Thanks for your time !

A.

**EDIT**

I should have stipulated few things :

1- The report is composed of hundred of stand-alone html files. It is basic html and javascript components that are translated by a classic web browser without the need of an internet connexion or a localhost server.

2- Folder structure :

```
root_folder
  |
  |---- index.html (main page to access all sub pages)
  |---- graphics
          |---- graphic1.html
          |---- graphic2.html
```

3- People need to share the report on their own and there is no user database. The only constraint is that after performing a modification on an editable content box, the text should be written somewhere in the folder structure (see 2) and retrieved automatically the next time some user (either the original editor or the next one on an other computer as long as the first editor shared the whole directory with its own edit) will open (or refresh) the html file.

I know that there are better solutions but I really have to stick with a stand-alone solution for now, hoping that there is a solution to this issue !

Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no server-side component and you don't want to use the browser's (sandboxed) local storage (be that LocalStorage, IndexedDb or otherwise) then you are left with `FileReader` to read data and creating `Blob` URLs to download data.

The user experience would be something like this:

1. The user opens your (local) .html file
2. They are prompted to open the database (could be text file(s)) with a `<input type="file">`.
3. You use the [FileReader api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to load this file. Note: you can't use `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` to do this automatically.
4. When the user has finished entered their content, store it in a [Blob object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) and then create a `data:`-link with [`createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL). You could put that generated url in a `<a href="..." download>Save</a>` link.

As it would be up to your users to make sure they select the proper database file(s) and to save them under the right file name, this is not ideal. I would strongly recommend a (self-)hosted solution. That could deal with multiple concurrent users a whole lot better, too.

A server-side component doesn't have to be complex: If you start in a language you're comfortable with and use a SQLite database, you'll go very far in a less complex set-up than what you're describing.

Comment: Hi RickN,
Thanks for your quick yet detailed answer, I really appreciate.
I should detailed more the issue actually, the fact is I'm not avoiding server-side solution but I want this solution to be stand-alone (ie every user could edit the document as long as they have the full report directory and something that can open the html (**no internet connexion required neither**). I tried the **LocalStorage** solution but from what I understand it uses user cookie-like system storage and hence modification are lost when the folder containing the report is shared on an **other computer**.

Comment: In that case, I see little other options than to implement something as described in my answer: Have the user manually open a database with FileReader and after making changes have them download/save the database, overwriting the existing one. The choice between one "master" database or one for every report .html file is yours. Just keep in mind that users may overwrite the wrong database file / save it in the wrong location / overwrite their colleague's changes.

Comment: Thanks again for your time. As long as there are not hundred of collaborators, the solution you proposed should work fine. Best